# CKAN: custom authentication but with default session handling

Tags: authentication, ckan

What is the most direct approach to implement a hook into the CKAN login mechanism, that allows one to define which user to log in based on apache environment headers instead of validating username/password.

When writing a plugin that implements `ckan.plugins.IAuthenticator` the class requires both a `login()` and an `identify()` method. Thus one has to define a way of keeping track of the user.

However, we want to simply check whether certain trusted information (Shibboleth environment variables) is available and then to log in the corresponding user, in effect just bypassing the login form, leaving all session handling up to the CKAN internals.

Answer (score 2):

Can you write an `IAuthenticator` plugin with an `identify()` method that looks for these environment variables, and if you don't need the `login()` method then just leave it blank?

```
def login(self):
    pass
```

I think that should work. CKAN calls `identify()` once for each request to decide which user is loggged in. It calls `login()` once each time the login form is submitted.

Apart from the `identify()` check on each request, the rest of CKAN's session handling will continue to work as normal with your plugin.

Comment: I am looking for the opposite. The `identify()` method is for session handling. So in effect I want my plugin to only have the `login()` method and pass for `identify()`, implementing `login()` such that the default mechanism kicks in on page loads. (this allows us to protect the login-page by shibboleth but not the entire CKAN site)